# (Google Script) Need Help Figuring Out How To Reduce Calls to Google Script Services in Creating Google Forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-sheets-api

I'm new here, so apologies if my formatting/approach needs some work.

I am currently working to write a google script that produces individualized surveys (google forms) that will be shared with folks who answered a very similar survey a year ago.

I have a google spreadsheet with all the questions for the survey, as well as individuals' former responses.

The script seems to be working (producing individualized forms w/ spreadsheet data); however, the issue I am having is that the **script takes too long to run** and I ran out of time. It can produce about 10 surveys in the 6 minutes before timing out, so I have been producing them in chunks, but I just ran out of my daily time limit on google script calls.

Does anyone have any **recommendations on how to make this code more efficiently** produce individualized surveys?

As guide to how the code is working now (I think), it pulls in the spreadsheet data in the first few lines, then runs a for loop for each school, and then within that for loop runs another for loop that populates each question in the form.

I can provide the spreadsheet and example form it has produced if necessary.

Thanks for any advice.

-Nick

```
function pullDataMakeForm() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange("Sheet1!A1:CL70")
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var tempr = i+7;  
        var schoolName = data[1][tempr];
        var form1 = FormApp.create("Profile Survey - " + schoolName).setAllowResponseEdits(true)
            .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding!')
            .setDescription("This is the profile survey. Your answers from last year have been provided below each question."); //makes form

        form1.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, 'spreadsheetID');

        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; ++j) {
            var row = data[j];
            var questionText = row[2];
            var questionType = row[4];
            var questionDescription = row[i+7];
            var newSection = row[6];
            var sectionTitle = row[1];

            if (newSection == "Y") {
                var item0 = form1.addSectionHeaderItem();
                item0.setTitle(sectionTitle);
            }

            if (questionType == "Short Answer") {
                var item1 = form1.addTextItem()
                item1.setTitle(questionText).setHelpText(questionDescription) /*addItem1*/
            } else if (questionType == "Paragraph") {
                var item2 =form1.addParagraphTextItem()
                item2.setTitle(questionText).setRequired(false).setHelpText(questionDescription)
            } else if (questionType == "Date") {
                var item4 = form1.addDateItem()
                item4.setTitle(questionText).setRequired(false).setHelpText(questionDescription)
            } else if (questionType == "Multiple Choice"){
                var item3 = form1.addMultipleChoiceItem()
                item3.setTitle(questionText)
                .setRequired(false).setHelpText(questionDescription).setChoices([
                    item3.createChoice('Yes'),
                    item3.createChoice('No')
                ])
                .showOtherOption(false);     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm totally new to programming - never had any training or anything, this is the first google script / java script thing i've ever done. How do I avoid the double loop?

Comment: Well it's not that complicated.  If you have a 100 records in your data set and you loop through them with an outer loop and a nested inner loop then you'll end up having performed 10,000 iterations versus 100.  I don't think that's above anyone's head. So I would just try to rework the loop so that you just go through it 1 time.

Comment: Could you share some of your data.  Maybe if we see how it's structured some of the double looping might make some sense.

Comment: Example spreadsheet data (with information mostly stripped) is available here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17A5Rn6K4wqEKGFSacsqK1DVSm4XhDddGjKVnS-0ESOA/edit?usp=sharing.

Thanks for your help - I get that I need to avoid double looping now, just not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: Would you mind reposting your code again.  I'd like to start with it and try to make a few improvements if possible and see if we can't figure out a better solution for you.

Comment: I haven't changed the code so I'm not sure what to repost. The posted code above is what I'm working with.

Comment: Someone edited your post yesterday and I just wanted to start with your code rather than the edited code.

Comment: all he did was fix the tabs/indents and switch the i/j variables order-wise, everything else is the same

Answer (score 0):

I think the loop idea you had is sensible.  What I didn't know was that the data for each form comes from data that is stored in consecutive columns so the first loop is now looping over columns and the second loop is looping over rows.

It was working before because it just needs to increment by one each time to get to the next column.  But you were probably continuing to loop even after running out of columns because you were looping rows instead of columns.

```
function pullDataMakeForm() 
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var nameRange=sheet.getRange("H3:CL3");//The range of all school names
    var name=nameRange.getValues();
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:CL70");//The range of all question data with data for each school in consecutive columns
    var data=dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < name[0].length; ++i)//loops over columns 
    {
        var schoolName = name[0][i];
        var form1 = FormApp.create("Profile Survey - " + schoolName).setAllowResponseEdits(true)
            .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding!')
            .setDescription("This is the profile survey. Your answers from last year have been provided below each question."); 

        form1.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, 'spreadsheetID');

        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; ++j)//loops over rows 
        {
            var row = data[j];
            var questionText = row[2];
            var questionType = row[4];
            var questionDescription = row[i+7];//move one column to the right with each new school
            var newSection = row[6];
            var sectionTitle = row[1];

            if (newSection == "Y") 
            {
                var item0 = form1.addSectionHeaderItem();
                item0.setTitle(sectionTitle);
            }

            if (questionType == "Short Answer") 
            {
                var item1 = form1.addTextItem()
                item1.setTitle(questionText).setHelpText(questionDescription) /*addItem1*/
            } else if (questionType == "Paragraph") 
            {
                var item2 =form1.addParagraphTextItem()
                item2.setTitle(questionText).setRequired(false).setHelpText(questionDescription)
            } else if (questionType == "Date") {
                var item4 = form1.addDateItem()
                item4.setTitle(questionText).setRequired(false).setHelpText(questionDescription)
            } else if (questionType == "Multiple Choice")
            {
                var item3 = form1.addMultipleChoiceItem()
                item3.setTitle(questionText)
                .setRequired(false).setHelpText(questionDescription).setChoices([
                    item3.createChoice('Yes'),
                    item3.createChoice('No')
                ])
                .showOtherOption(false);     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't get into the logic of the questions because I've only built a couple of forms recently so I don't really know that much about it.

Comment: yep, the program never finished so it didn't actually run through extra columns, as it kept timing out once it hit 6 minutes and would make ~10 forms, which limited me to 60 forms per day with google's one hour cap. So, it's taken a few days and some tweaks but I've got the forms done now. Thanks for the time you spent trying to help, it's appreciated. Good experience w/ my first question here.

Comment: Trying using the logger. Record the  i and j indexes and perhaps you can figure where it's failing.  Also look at Developer tools and read the errors carefully looking line numbers in your code script files.  Chrome developer tools can catch google script errors sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is currently over your head, but I'll give you a boost:

## cache

Use google sheets to *store* the data, and cache it on your server(s) as needed. Because of your limited requests, you may want to create a program that runs on a set schedule to update the cache. This will allow you to lookup the data *first* in the cache, and make the service request as needed, or it can be en-queued (to be run later by the said scheduled program).

## data structures and algorithms

It looks like you are trying to iterate the table rows * columns, but the double loop is unnecessary here and notoriously known as quadratic 
 in terms of algorithmic complexity.

- stop calling the same functions again and again without saving the result to a variable and reusing it.
- stop making useless variables that are not used  elsewhere

## educate yourself

read about programming, algorithms and data structures, os theory, theory of computation, etc.

here are some books I recommend for you, *most are short* and very enlightening:

- the c programming language
- the practice of programming
- CLRS algorithms
- design patterns (gang of four)
- theory of computation - sipser
- some OS theory book
- the elements of style (strunk)

Believe it or not, you could read only the list above, and get very far in the field (with or without a degree), good luck.